# How do I solve this Error with Array Dimensionality

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I tried to follow a tutorial on Machine learning Algothim and I keep getting this error. It kept giving me this error I have tried all manner of debugging and still getting the same error message. What do I do?

Stack overflow doesn't want me to post all code so i tried to short the error message

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

numberImages = datasets.load_digits()

supportVectorClassifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.0001, C=100)

x = numberImages.data[:-5]
y = numberImages.target[:-5]
supportVectorClassifier.fit(x,y)

predictedImage = numberImages.data[-4]

print ("Assume the image is: ", supportVectorClassifier.predict(predictedImage))

plt.imshow(numberImages.images[-4],cmap = plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\...\Documents\Algorithim\App.py", line 15, in <module>
    print ("Assume the image is: ", supportVectorClassifier.predict(predictedImage))
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 810, in predict
    y = super().predict(X)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 433, in predict
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 611, in _validate_for_predict
    X = self._validate_data(
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 577, in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, input_name="X", **check_params)
py", line 879, in check_array
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 0.  0.  6. 16. 13. 11.  1.  0.  0.  0. 16. 15. 12. 16.  1.  0.  0.  3.
 16.  7.  0. 13.  6.  0.  0.  4. 16.  0.  0. 10.  8.  0.  0.  8. 16.  0.
  0. 14.  6.  0.  0.  5. 16.  7.  9. 16.  5.  0.  0.  1. 15. 16. 16. 16.
  1.  0.  0.  0.  6. 16. 14.  6.  0.  0.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it 
contains a single sample.
PS C:\Users\...> & C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/.../Documents/Algorithim/App.py"C:\Users\RESIDENT_ALIEN3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 810, in predict
    y = super().predict(X)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 433, in predict
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 611, in _validate_for_predict
    X = self._validate_data(
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 577, in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, input_name="X", **check_params)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 879, in check_array
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 0.  0.  6. 16. 13. 11.  1.  0.  0.  0. 16. 15. 12. 16.  1.  0.  0.  3.
 16.  7.  0. 13.  6.  0.  0.  4. 16.  0.  0. 10.  8.  0.  0.  8. 16.  0.
  0. 14.  6.  0.  0.  5. 16.  7.  9. 16.  5.  0.  0.  1. 15. 16. 16. 16.
  1.  0.  0.  0.  6. 16. 14.  6.  0.  0.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it 
contains a single sample
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your error, it states that the function expects a 2D array but you only passed a 1D array. This happens because `predictedImage = numberImages.data[-4]` returns a 1D array.

If you take another look at your stacktrace, you can see `Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample`. Since in your case you have a single sample, you need to reshape `predictedImage` with `reshape(1, -1)`. This gives you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

numberImages = datasets.load_digits()

supportVectorClassifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.0001, C=100)

x = numberImages.data[:-5]
y = numberImages.target[:-5]
supportVectorClassifier.fit(x, y)

predictedImage = numberImages.data[-4]

predictedImage = predictedImage.reshape(1, -1)

print("Assume the image is: ", supportVectorClassifier.predict(predictedImage))

plt.imshow(numberImages.images[-4], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I couldn't have taught about reshaping the array. I really appreciate this